# Reverse engeneering on remult.dev entities

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm, prisma

I need assistance on get the Remult.dev entities rebuild from database tables.
Typeorm is ok to build entities from database, but they are so diferent from remult entities. Prisma is also a lot diferent.

Anybody knows how to handle this? I have around 200 tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was looking for this problem's solution. But there are no answer :(. Somebody please create code gen prisma to remult please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source project that does that called `remult-cli`

You can find it at:
https://github.com/Yedidyar/remult-cli/

It currently supports postgres, but if you need an other database - post an issue and they'll implement it

Comment: sorry to say , but nothing is generated...only a file empty _entities.ts

Comment: Try opening an issue for the maintainers of that project:
https://github.com/Yedidyar/remult-cli/issues

Comment: Its ok now...thanks Noam